# Depth first search to a path

Tags: java, path-finding

I have a problem requiring me to implement an algorithm finding path from a character to another character with obstacles along the way.

I know there are a lot of advanced pathfinding algorithms(A*, BFS, DFS,dijkstra....). However, I am struggling to implement all these concepts in my code after plenty of research and attempts, and also I don't think I am required to implement all these advanced algorithms.

"Shortest" path is not the requirement, and all I need is a path that can lead my character to another character by avoiding moving onto obstacles. 
Can anyone give me an idea (maybe some algorithms better than backtracking)or useful website (similar examples) for this problem?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you post some Code? What u tried and what u have ?

Comment: Why u don't want to take a real pathfinding algorithm like A*?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you the A* algortihm.
Its easy to implements the algorithm. For my A* i used the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) code and the [geekforgeek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/) code.

I'll post my code aswell its in C# but very similiar to java:

```
public List<ANote> findPath(ANote start, ANote end)
        {
            if (start == null || end == null || start == end || !start.walkable || !end.walkable)
                return null;


        List<ANote> openSet = new List<ANote>();
        List<ANote> closedSet = new List<ANote>();

        start.parent = null;
        openSet.Add(start);
        start.h = getDistance(start, end);

        while (openSet.Any())
        {
            openSet = openSet.OrderBy(o => o.f).ToList();
            ANote current = openSet[0];

            if (current == end)
                break;

            openSet.Remove(current);
            closedSet.Add(current);

            foreach (ANote neighbor in current.adjacted)
            {
                if (closedSet.Contains(neighbor))
                    continue;


                double _gScore = current.g + 1; // For me every distance was 1

                if (openSet.Contains(neighbor) && _gScore >= neighbor.g)
                    continue;

                if (!openSet.Contains(neighbor))
                    openSet.Add(neighbor);


                neighbor.parent = current;
                neighbor.g = _gScore;
                neighbor.h = getDistance(neighbor, end);
            }
        }

        return reconstructPath(start, end);
    }

    private List<ANote> reconstructPath(ANote start, ANote end)
    {
        List<ANote> backNotes = new List<ANote>();
        ANote current = end;
        while (current.parent != null)
        {
            backNotes.Add(current);
            current = current.parent;
        }


        return backNotes;
    }

public class ANote
    {
        public ANote parent { get; set; }
        public double f { get { return g + h; } }
        public double g { get; set; }
        public double h { get; set; }
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
        public bool walkable { get; set; }

        public List<ANote> adjacted { get; set; } = new List<ANote>();

        public ANote(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            walkable = true;
        }
    }
```

Important for this code is that you must define the adjacted nodes and which are walkable and what are not before you search.
I hope my code can help you to implement A* in your code.

Comment: thank you for this. I will have a careful look at this algorithm again

Answer (score 0):

Since I have no idea how your "Grid" is described, and what "Cell" is, I assume the grid is rectangular, the cells only map the objects on it, not the empty spaces.

I suggest you make an `char[][] array = new char[rows][columns];` (or char) initialize it with some value and iterate over `Cells`, fill the 2D array in some meaningful manner, the example is `G` for goal, `#` for obstacle, etc. Then you start a DFS from Goal to look for Start.

You need to store the correct path somewhere, so you need a `ArrayList list;` variable too. Since it's a list, you can add items to it with `list.add(item);`, which is handy.

### Non-optimal path: DFS

DFS is a really basic recursive algorithm, in your case it will go like this:

```
bool DFS(list, array, row, column):
    if(array[row][column] == '#' or
       array[row][column] == 'v') return False; # Obstacle or visited, ignore it
    if( ...               == 'S') return True;  # It's the Start, path found

    array[row][column] = 'v'; # mark as visited, nothing interesting.
    # If you want the shortest path, you're supposed to put here the distance from goal,
    #that you would pass on and increment as additional argument of DFS 

    #Check for edge cases, or initialize array to be bigger and place obstacles on edge#
    if( DFS(list, array, row-1, column) ){ # If DFS fount a path to Start from cell above
        list.add("Move Up");               # Then you add a direction to go below to the list
        return True;                       # And then tell the previous DFS, that the path was found
    }
    if()
    if()
    if()
    # And then you add the checks for the other directions in a similar manner

    return False; # You didn't find anything anywhere
}
```

That is not the code, but it should be enough for you to do your **assignement** from there.

Chances are it'll find a path like this:

```
...→→→→↓
...↑.↓←↓
...S.F↑↓
......↑↓
......↑←
```

But in grids with a lot of obstacles or only one correct path it'll make more reasonable paths. Also you can improve it by selecting the order you try directions in so it always tries to go towards Goal first, but that's a pain.

### Optimal path: augmented DFS

To find the shortest path usually people refer to A*, but I read up on it and it's not as I remember it and it's just unnecessarily complicated, so I'll explain an expanded DFS. It takes a little longer to find the answer, than A* or BFS would, but for reasonably-sized grids it's not noticeable.

The idea of the algorithm is to map the entire grid with distances to `Goal` and then walk from start to goal following decreasing distance.

First you will need to use `int[][] array` instead of `char` of the previous case. That is because you need to store distances, which char can too to some extent, but also non-distance markers in the grid, like obstacles and such.

The idea of the algorithm is you call `DFS(array, row, col, distance)`, where `distance` is calculated as distance of the `Cell` that calls DFS incremented by 1. Then DFS in the next cell checks if the distance it was passed is smaller than its current distance, if it is so, then there was a shorter path found to that cell and you need to recalculate all its neighbors too. Otherwise the new path is longer and you can disregard it. By calling DFS recursively you will gradually map the entire maze.

After that you will call another function `FindPath(list, array, row, col)`, that will check the Cell it started in and add a direction to the cell with `neighbor.distance == (this.distance - 1)` to the `list` and then call `FindPath` on that neighbor until distance is 0, at which point it's the goal.

It should look smth like this:

```
main()
{
    # initialize grid with Integer.MAX_VALUE or just a big enough number
    # for Cell in Cells -> put obstacles on Grid as -1,
    #                      find the Start and Goal and record them somewhere
    # DFS_plus(array, Goal, 0);
    # FindPath(list, array, Start);
    # Done
}


void DFS_plus(array, row, column, distance):
    if(array[row][col] <= distance) return; # There already exists a shorter path there
    # or it's an obstacle, we store obstacles as -1. 
    # It's smaller than any possible path and thus blocks further search

    array[row][column] = distance; # update distance.
    # If this happened its neighbors will need to be updated too.

    #Check for edge cases, or initialize array to be bigger and place obstacles on edge#

    DFS_plus(array, row-1, column, distance+1); # You just map everything, no returns expected
    DFS_plus(); # For all 4 directions
    DFS_plus();
    DFS_plus();
}

FindPath(list, array, row, col){
    if(array[row][col] == 0) return; # It's the Goal

    if(array[row-1][col] == (array[row][col] - 1)){ # Check if Cell above is 1 closer to Goal
        list.add("MoveUp");                           # Add direction
        FindPath(list, array, row-1, col);          # Look for next direction
        return; # You don't need to check other directions as path is guaranteed
    }
    if(){}; # Check other directions if Up wasn't the one
    if(){};
    if(){};
}
```

It is not much more complicated, but it gets you the shortest path. It's not the quickest way to find the shortest path, but it's relatively simple as any recursive algoithm.

Comment: thank you for that IcedLance. I would try your approach.

Comment: I can run the code without error. However, the object goes to a weird distance instead of approaching the target. is it because I didn't put the shortest distance condition?

Comment: Yeah, I've apparently misunderstood A*, but I've added a rather simple solution that does search for shortest path. Alternatively you can add heuristics to ordinary DFS so it always tries to first go the direction of Start, but that's gotta add a lot of `if`s and I don't like them.